# cursor not at beginning of commentform field

Tags: comment-form

Is this a feature or a bug? When I place my cursor somewhere in the new and empty commentform field, it does not appear at the beginning of that field, as expected, but at some lines under the top, and quite a few characters insert.
It is possible to replace the cursor at the beginning, though.

But 'something' makes that the cursor does not start directly there.

Is there someone maybe that has a clue?

Many thanks....!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is this in EE backend, or one of your templates?
typically a comment field would be a text area tag - as such it has an opening and a closing tag. so in the html check to see if there is spaces, newlines, etc between the two and that is probably the culprit.
if not - CSS padding maybe? but not if you have space characters in there...

Comment: Thanks. It is on the front end. The tag is the plain {comment}. No CSS involved. First I thought the field had placeholder text invisible, but at close look it is empty. But I can copy and past these empty characters in Textwrangler. They just occupy 'space'.

Comment: And there were spaces and a new line in the HTML which I did not notice first, my apologies. But you helped me, Nevsie - Modeten, thanks!